# Installed Ubuntu 11.10, got a blank screen upon login

Tags: ubuntu-11.10

And no, right-clicking does nothing; only the power switch gets it to give me any options at all. Please advise! Urgent for a job!

Comment: Although you have not said so (including this type of information is a good idea), I _imagine_ that the install process gave no errors, that the first boot got you to a working graphical login manager, that this machine (specifically your home folder) is freshly formatted and that no other OS is installed. Am I correct?

Comment: If you hit ctrl+alt+f1 and type in "startx" does it tell you that no useable config is found? Alternatively have you tried ctrl+alt+f1 followed by ctrl+alt+f7?

Comment: Yes, terdon, no hitches on install, but the machine still runs Windows as well, hence the boot gave me the option of OSs. (Even though the guy who sent me the link said it would wipe the hard drive.)

Comment: Snasticle: when I type ctrl+alt+f1 it says "ubuntu login:", I type "starx" and it says "password:", but my password isn't accepted...ctrl+alt+f7 brings me back to the same unclickable screen.

Comment: Perhaps I should have specified that you'll need to login at the command prompt before typing in "startx".

Comment: Yes, `startx` is a command that starts the windowing environment. So you will need to log in at the text prompt first before you can run that.

Comment: No change from either command...

Comment: @user185096 So, when you run `startx`, you get the same black screen?